# Output cell appearance difference in Jupyter Notebook in local host and VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, output, appearance

Attaching screenshots of the appearance of the output cells when I run my Jupyter Notebook in two different ways.

This is the appearance when I run the notebook using **the local host via the command line** :
[Jupyter Notebook output via local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBlYe.jpg)

This is the appearance when I run the notebook using **VS Code** :
[Jupyter Notebook output via VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhUmh.jpg)

As you can appreciate the output cell in the local host is better formatted especially with regards to alignment and indentation. Moreover, the overall appearance of even the other outputs like the model details is not very satisfactory and pleasing. Above all the alignment always seems to be messed up in VS Code Jupyter Notebook output.

Have thoroughly searched online for a solution but of no avail. Any help in this query will be highly appreciated,

I'm using VS Code 1.77.3, Python 3.10.9, and Windows 11.

I searched online for a solution but could not really get an answer. I even scanned the VS Code settings but still could not find a solution.

As per the suggestion mentioned, have raised an issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/180594

Comment: what version of VS Code do you have installed? this could be a regression of https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/144417 / https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/144579